# Multiple browser in same Zalenium container

Tags: docker, zalenium

[image]

Executing multiple browsers in the same node

I wish to launch several nodes that each run several browsers

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock       -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start   --browserStackEnabled false --maxTestSessions 4  --desiredContainers 2 --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 4
```

when executing this script I get 2 containers each having only one browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zalenium will have always only one browser per container, this helps to isolate each test in its own environment and simplifies the tasks of video recording and logs collection.

Answer (score 0):

Each Zalenium node(Container) has 2 browsers instances (Firefox & Chome) by default.
It then uses the one specified in the code

See screenshot [Bowsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOmk5.png)